# Debugging in Code Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I just installed Code block to run c programs. I installed tdm64-gcc compiler too. When  I try to execute a simple program an error outputs. 
[I think something goes wrong with my debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcpZz.png).

Can someone help to fix this? I think my compiler settings are configured ok.

And this is a [screenshot of debugger setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIDF9.png).

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other file with `main` in same project ?

Comment: [As you can see here](http://ideone.com/F78E9Y) the code is ok. There is something wrong into your project, such as 2 files compiled, both with `main` funcion..

Comment: @ameyCU Oh thanks! I really had another file with main in the same project. I thought it worked likje in Eclipse,where u can include many files with main in the same project.

Comment: @ameyCU So I have to create a new project for each new file with main? o.O

Comment: @user5827762  Yes , _if each file need a_ `main` function . Else you can create functions in files in projects and call them as you need .

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong on your code but maybe you have two `main` files on your project with same name.You must **delete** one of them.